# How to search for specific items in a SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online, custom-lists

I want to know if there is a way to search a sharepoint list for specific items. So in my list there is around 4,000 items, each with a specific Issue ID, the searchbar in the top left does not search for the issue ID it searches for something completely different as it never returns the correct item. IssueID is the first colum in the list.

At the moment, I'm having to export the list to excel and use CTRL+F to find specific items. Is there any possible way of changing the search bar so that it serahces for Issue ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the column to the search schema so it is indexed, otherwise the column wont be pulled into the search results.

There's a guide here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/o365totd/2015/12/11/using-site-columns-to-create-searchable-metadata-in-sharepoint-online-office-365/